# Definition of the Kernel of a Lie algebra homomorphism

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-algebras

So, my question is the following:

I would like to know the precise definition of the kernel $\ker\phi$ of a Lie algebra homomorphism $\phi: \mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}'$. As far as I know, the kernel of a homomorphism $f:A\to B$, in general, is the set of the elements of $A$ that are mapped to the identity element of $B$. I have seen in 
[Kernel of a Lie Algebra Homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316591/kernel-of-a-lie-algebra-homomorphism) a precise definition in the special case of Lie algebra homomorphisms, going as the following
$$\ker\phi=\{X\in\mathfrak{g}:\hspace{0.3cm} \phi(X)=0\}.$$
However, I am troubled with the element $0$. Is $0$ supposed to mean the "identity" element of $\mathfrak{g}'$ seen as a vector space, i.e. the zero vector $0\in\mathfrak{g}'$?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The Lie algebra is, in fact, a vector space.

Comment: @DiegoMath Yes, I know that. Do you mean that my thinking is correct? I mean, is $0$ the "identity" element of $\mathfrak{g}'$?

Comment: Yes, you thinking is correct.

Comment: Yes, $0$ is the zero vector, the additive identity of the underlying Abelian group of the vector space structure underlying the Lie algebra structure.

Comment: @Berci Thank you very much for your answer!